# How to write a function to get user inputs through ipywidgets and write them to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, ipywidgets

I only recently started using ipywidgets and I am stuck. I am trying to make a function which takes in a dataframe and a list of options, finds rows where 'Practice Area' is empty, allows user to pick the right Practice Area for this particular record (pick Practice Area from options) and then makes a dictionary (matter: area).

```
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets

def make_NA_dict(df, options):
    list_of_NAs = df[df['Practice Area'].isna()].groupby('Matter Number').count().index.tolist()
    NA_dict = {}

    def capture_choice(matter, option):
        NA_dict[matter] = option

    for matter in list_of_NAs:
        print(f"Choose practice for {matter}")
        interact(lambda option: capture_choice(matter, option), option=widgets.Dropdown(options=options, value="Other", description="Practice: "))
    while True:
        if input('Type "Done" to finish ').lower() == 'done':
            return NA_dict
```

I thought the version above was working but it writes the dictionary with a default value ('Other' in this case) and doesn't care for what user picks. Is this even possible to implement?

Expected to receive a user-populated dictionary, but I am getting a default value everywhere. Trying to modify the function myself didn't help

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the example code has not tried to use the `ipwidgets`. so where is the attempt or error ?

Comment: Apologies, added the libraries import, interact is a part of ipywidgets